# Apache Ignite.NET LINQ Failure

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, ignite

Using Apache Ignite .NET 2.3.0

Trying to search using Linq extension (Apache.Ignite.Linq).

Here is a IgniteConfig:

```
{
    ClientMode = false,
    JvmInitialMemoryMb = 512,
    JvmMaxMemoryMb = 512,
    MetricsLogFrequency = TimeSpan.Zero, // disable metrics output
    DataStorageConfiguration = new Apache.Ignite.Core.Configuration.DataStorageConfiguration()
    {
        DefaultDataRegionConfiguration = new DataRegionConfiguration()
        {
            Name = "DefaultRegion",
            PersistenceEnabled = true
        },
        StoragePath = _config.Value.Ignite.PersistentStoragePath
     },
     CacheConfiguration = new[]
     {
         new CacheConfiguration 
         {
             Name = "securitiesItemsCache",
             ReadThrough = false,
             WriteThrough = false,
             CacheMode = CacheMode.Replicated,
             DataRegionName = "DefaultRegion",
             QueryEntities = new []
             {
                  new QueryEntity(typeof(string), typeof(SecuritiesItem))
             }
         }

    }
```

Getting cache:

```
_securitiesCache = _ignite.GetOrCreateCache<string, SecuritiesItem>("securitiesItemsCache");
```

Searching like this:

```
_securitiesCache
    .AsCacheQueryable()
    .Where(s => s.Value.SearchString.Contains(query))
    .ToArray()
    .Select(x => x.Value);
```

In this case recieve exception:

> Apache.Ignite.Core.Common.IgniteException   HResult=0x80131500
>   Message=Failed to parse query: select _T0._KEY, _T0._VAL from
>   "securitiesItemsCache".SECURITIESITEM as _T0 where (_T0.SearchString
>   like '%' || ? || '%')    Source=Apache.Ignite.Core   StackTrace:    at
>   Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Unmanaged.UnmanagedCallbacks.Error(Void*
>   target, Int32 errType, SByte* errClsChars, Int32 errClsCharsLen,
>   SByte* errMsgChars, Int32 errMsgCharsLen, SByte* stackTraceChars,
>   Int32 stackTraceCharsLen, Void* errData, Int32 errDataLen)    at
>   Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Unmanaged.IgniteJniNativeMethods.TargetInStreamOutObject(Void*
>   ctx, Void* target, Int32 opType, Int64 memPtr)    at
>   Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.PlatformJniTarget.InStreamOutObject(Int32
>   type, Action`1 writeAction)    at
>   Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Cache.CacheImpl`2.QueryFields[T](SqlFieldsQuery
>   qry, Func`3 readerFunc)    at
>   Remotion.Linq.Clauses.StreamedData.StreamedSequenceInfo.ExecuteQueryModel(QueryModel
>   queryModel, IQueryExecutor executor)    at
>   Apache.Ignite.Linq.Impl.CacheFieldsQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression
>   expression)    at Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.LargeArrayBuilder`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1
>   items)    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1
>   source)    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1
>   source)    at Core.IgniteServer.SearchSecurities(String query) in
>   C:\development\ISSDPService\Core\IgniteServer.cs:line 138    at
>   WebService.Providers.IgniteProvider.Search(String query,
>   LanguagePrefix lang) in
>   C:\development\ISSDPService\WebService\Providers\IgniteProvider.cs:line
>   78    at WebService.Controllers.SecuritiesController.Search(String
>   query) in
>   C:\development\ISSDPService\WebService\Controllers\SecuritiesController.cs:line
>   47    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object
>   target, Object[] parameters)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__12.MoveNext()
>
> Inner Exception 1: JavaException: class
>   org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to parse query:
>   select _T0._KEY, _T0._VAL from "securitiesItemsCache".SECURITIESITEM
>   as _T0 where (_T0.SearchString like '%' || ? || '%')      at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.utils.PlatformUtils.unwrapQueryException(PlatformUtils.java:519)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.cache.PlatformCache.runFieldsQuery(PlatformCache.java:1240)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.cache.PlatformCache.processInStreamOutObject(PlatformCache.java:877)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.PlatformTargetProxyImpl.inStreamOutObject(PlatformTargetProxyImpl.java:79)
>   Caused by: javax.cache.CacheException: class
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.IgniteSQLException: Failed
>   to parse query: select _T0._KEY, _T0._VAL from
>   "securitiesItemsCache".SECURITIESITEM as _T0 where (_T0.SearchString
>   like '%' || ? || '%')     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.query(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:597)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.query(GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.java:368)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.cache.PlatformCache.runFieldsQuery(PlatformCache.java:1234)
>     ... 2 more Caused by: class
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.IgniteSQLException: Failed
>   to parse query: select _T0._KEY, _T0._VAL from
>   "securitiesItemsCache".SECURITIESITEM as _T0 where (_T0.SearchString
>   like '%' || ? || '%')     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.queryDistributedSqlFields(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1385)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$5.applyx(GridQueryProcessor.java:1909)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$5.applyx(GridQueryProcessor.java:1907)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.util.lang.IgniteOutClosureX.apply(IgniteOutClosureX.java:36)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.executeQuery(GridQueryProcessor.java:2445)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.querySqlFields(GridQueryProcessor.java:1914)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.query(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:585)
>     ... 4 more Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Столбец
>   "_T0.SEARCHSTRING" не найден Column "_T0.SEARCHSTRING" not found; SQL
>   statement: select _T0._KEY, _T0._VAL from
>   "securitiesItemsCache".SECURITIESITEM as _T0 where (_T0.SearchString
>   like '%' || ? || '%')  [42122-195]    at
>   org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
>     at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)     at
>   org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)  at
>   org.h2.expression.ExpressionColumn.optimize(ExpressionColumn.java:147)
>     at org.h2.expression.CompareLike.optimize(CompareLike.java:93)  at
>   org.h2.command.dml.Select.prepare(Select.java:842)    at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:262)     at
>   org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:573)  at
>   org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:514)    at
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1204)
>     at
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:73)
>     at
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:288)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.prepareStatement(IgniteH2Indexing.java:402)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.queryDistributedSqlFields(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1365)
>     ... 10 more

it says:

> Column "_T0.SEARCHSTRING" not found; SQL statement:

But is't `new QueryEntity(typeof(string), typeof(SecuritiesItem))` enought fo this?

**Resolved**

Added description for field programmatically:

```
Fields = new []
{
    new QueryField { Name = "SearchString", FieldType = typeof(string)}
}
```

**Another problem**.

It searching great if query consists only of English letters. But if i enter Russian characters, then nothing finds. Should I convert the text into a specific encoding?

Comment: Please provide complete exception details (i.e. call `ex.ToString()`).

Comment: updated exception text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `Column "_T0.SEARCHSTRING" not found`

You should mark `SearchString` property with `[QuerySqlField]`.

SQL is opt-in, you should explicitly configure which fields should be available in queries. See https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/net-schema-and-indexes.

Comment: Updated question with resolve section and new propblem.
works great, what can you advise about not English characters?

Comment: I tried with russian letters and it works. Can you double check? Does it work with `==` but not with `Contains`?

Comment: Please ask a separate question with a minimal reproducer if it still does not work.

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47697413/apache-ignite-net-sql-not-searching-for-non-english-characters