# Apache Ignite.NET SQL not searching for non english characters

Tags: c#, .net-core, ignite

Using Apache Ignite .NET 2.3.0
Trying to search using Linq extension (Apache.Ignite.Linq).

Configuration:

```
     CacheConfiguration = new[]
     {
         new CacheConfiguration 
         {
             QueryEntities = new []
             {
                  new QueryEntity(typeof(string), typeof(SecuritiesItem))
                  {
                      Fields = new []
                      {
                          new QueryField { Name = "SearchString", FieldType = typeof(string)}
                      }
                  }
             }
         }
     }
```

SecuritiesItem definition:

```
public class SecuritiesItem
{
    /* all other fields */

    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public string SearchString { get; set; }
}
```

SearchString contains merged data from all fields what need to be used in search. Like this:

> Открытое акционерное общество " Рога и копыта
>   "#☢#Systems Open Joint-Stock Company#☢#ОАО
>   "РиК"#☢#Ssys#☢#335468321#☢#bner#☢#ОАО "РиК"#☢#
>   Systems Open Joint-Stock Company#☢#Открытое акционерное
>   общество "Рога и копыта"#☢#Systems
>   Open Joint-Stock Company#☢#RU003572593#☢#1-22-22222-A

Searching like this:

```
_securitiesCache
    .AsCacheQueryable()
    .Where(s => s.Value.SearchString.Contains(query))
    // or .Where(s => s.Value.SearchString.ToLower().IndexOf(query) != -1)
    .ToArray()
    .Select(x => x.Value);
```

So, if i searching for "Open" - it find everithing normally. But if i searching for "Откр", no results found.

Trying to search by specific field in object, like ShortName using '==', same result. Should I convert the text into a specific encoding?

**SelfResolved**

it's postman fault. https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2263 bug in url encoding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you share a sample project-reproducer?

I updated several tests and they work fine for a similar case. I did not change encoding or convert text into some specific encoding, it is in UTF-8 by default.

Comment: it's postman fault. https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2263 bug in url encoding.